# Postprossing error - copyTexImage2D: framebuffer is incompatible format

Tags: coffeescript, three.js, webgl

Postprossing error - copyTexImage2D: framebuffer is incompatible format

I'm trying to use the post effects as presented in the samples, but I keep getting the following error in my console and nothing is rendering. Any ideas on what might be causing this? I don't think anything that matters is different than in the postprocessing example.

WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: copyTexImage2D: framebuffer is incompatible format

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
renderer.setClearColorHex(0x000000, 1)
renderer.sortObjects = false;

...

composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer )
composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) )

effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.DotScreenShader )
effect.uniforms[ 'scale' ].value = 4
composer.addPass( effect )

effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FXAAShader )   
composer.addPass( effect )

render = ->
    requestAnimationFrame(render)
    composer.render()

render()
```

Comment: Does your scene render without the composer ?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to add alpha to the WebGLRenderer default framebuffer using:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the error, there's a bug where EffectComposer is incompatable with LensFlare, submitting a change.

Comment: It seems that this bug still exists. Have you managed to fix it somehow?

Comment: Hey, I seemed to have lost the change, but from a quick glance of the code, try changing EffectComposer.js:13 the format should be ARGB not just RGB. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Yep, lensflare fail with effectcomposer... r73
And yes @Axiverse your solution fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Basing on @Axiverse suggest, if your problem come with usage of lens flare (or maybe anything else...), simply add your own render target.

```
//...
var pixelRatio = renderer.getPixelRatio();
var width = Math.floor( renderer.context.canvas.width  / pixelRatio ) || 1;
var height = Math.floor( renderer.context.canvas.height / pixelRatio ) || 1;

var renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(width, height, {
    minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat, // <-- The line that fix all for me
    stencilBuffer: false
});

var effectComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer(webGLRenderer, renderTarget);
```